# Messages not sending all my texts to one specific user

Tags: macos, icloud, messages, sms

I upgraded to a new iMac running Catalina. Since I've done this I'm having a problem sending messages to my daughter and maybe others. At first she received no messages from me, but other people did. I fixed that problem using a solution from Ask Different. I thought the problem was solved. But now I found out that about a third of my messages don't get delivered to my daughter. We text several times a week and before my new iMac everything went thru fine. I text from my iMac, my iphone, and my iPad and in the past all three worked fine. Now they don't. It could be my daughters phone but it only happens with me. and likewise, as far as i know it only happens when I send to her. She doesn't receive it at all. Has anyone else had this problem or does anyone know what is maybe causing it?

Comment: Strong déjà-vu on this one. Lemme see if I can find the duplicates... two edits needed..  is your send from your AppleID or your cellular number or something else on the Mac. What build is your Mac (in about this Mac, click the version to see the build or `sw_vers`?

Comment: my mac model indentifier is iMac20,2.  The number using your method is  19G2021.  I'm not sure if my messages are sent thru my phone or using my email address.  How do I tell?

Comment: in messages -> preferences there is an option to start new conversations and it was set as my phone number. i saved it as using my email address.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the contact and manually recreate it again?

Comment: I just tried that. it'll take a while to know if it worked because its sporadic when it skips messages.  Sounds like a good option. i should have thought of that.  Thanks for your help!